# Materialize js is not wrking when add defer in script tag

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am facing a issue when I add async or defer in script tag

```
<script type='text/javascript' async defer src='materialize.js'></script>
```

I am getting error in console that M is not defined

```
uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined
```

here is what I am trying

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var elemt = document.querySelector('.carousel-top');
    var itm_elemt = document.querySelector('.carousel-item img');
    if(itm_elemt != null){
        elemt.style.height = itm_elemt.offsetHeight+'px';
    }
    M.Carousel.init(elemt, {numVisible : 3, dist:0, shift: 8});
});
```

I dont know how to resolve this error Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `async` or `defer`?

Let's say you have these scripts included in your page:

```
<script src="a.js"></script>
<script src="b.js"></script>
```

When adding `async` on them, they will be loaded asynchronously and executed as soon as they're downloaded. But their order of execution won't be preserved. If `a.js` takes a longer time to load, `b.js` will be executed first.

With `defer`, the files get downloaded asynchronously too, but they will always be executed in the same order as they were declared.

In your case, since your own script requires `materialize.js`, you will want to use `defer` to preserve the order.

## Why is `M` not defined?

The order will only be preserved between multiple `defer` scripts. I'm guessing you are not using `defer` on your own script. If it's in its own file, just add the attribute:

```
<script src="materialize.js" defer></script>
<script src="myScript.js" defer></script>
```

If your script is *inline* (i.e. directly inside your HTML), you could use the following technique, by loading `materialize.js` using JS instead of an HTML `<script>` tag and waiting for its `load` event to trigger:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Add the script in the page
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.onload = runMyScript;
  script.src = "materialize.js";
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  function runMyScript() {
    // M is now available
    var elemt = document.querySelector('.carousel-top');
    var itm_elemt = document.querySelector('.carousel-item img');
    if (itm_elemt != null) {
      elemt.style.height = itm_elemt.offsetHeight + 'px';
    }
    M.Carousel.init(elemt, {
      numVisible: 3,
      dist: 0,
      shift: 8
    });
  }
});
</script>
```